# cannot find symbol class android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback

Tags: android, android-proguard

I got an error in Android. Try to use

```
registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest request, ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback)
```

The api is for registers to receive notifications about all networks which satisfy the given NetworkRequest. [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback))

The error message is

```
Error:(29, 39) error: cannot find symbol class NetworkCallback
```

My understanding is NetworkCallback is a nested static class in android.net.ConnectivityManager. proguard.pro doesn't keep the class. So the compiler couldn't find it.

The code is

```
import android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback;

ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkRequest.Builder builder = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
    builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED);
    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);

    NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    };

    NetworkRequest networkRequest = builder.build();

    connMgr.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
    connMgr.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback);
}
```

proguard.pro is

```
-keep class android.net.** { *; }
```

gradle build is

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 25
```

How could to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do so with

```
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

...
...
```

then, i created a specific callback

```
private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback x = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestNetwork onAvailable()");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
             }

        } else {
            //This method was deprecated in API level 23
            ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
        }


       // Your job can be done here ..

       // then
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCapabilitiesChanged(Network network, NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestNetwork onCapabilitiesChanged()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLinkPropertiesChanged(Network network, LinkProperties linkProperties) {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestNetwork onLinkPropertiesChanged()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLosing(Network network, int maxMsToLive) {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestNetwork onLosing()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLost(Network network) {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestNetwork onLost()");
    }

};

...
...
```

and then, in your main program, for example, if you want to use a wifi connection, without internet access

```
   NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    builder.removeTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
    builder.removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
    NetworkRequest request = builder.build();
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, x);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at it.

Comment: Hi @ysimonx,  I have tried above code, I am able to connect cellular data when I have WIFI, But after some time, If i want come back to WIFI with below code you given not working. Please help how can I go back to WIFI from cellular, Cellular connected symbol should go off after WIFI connection.

builder.removeTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
    builder.removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);